# i3 - How can I change the mod key to AltGr and disable it for "normal" input

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, i3

I'd like to change the mod key to "AltGr" or "the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Furthermore I'd like to disable the new mod key for any other input in Linux. So when I am writing text in my text editor I don't want to get any Greek signs when commanding i3.

Answer (score 1):

See xmodmap.

Something like `xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Alt_R"`

Comment: But if the key is removed from xmodmap can I use it for my window manager?

Comment: You can bind it to another thing with xmodmap.

Comment: It will be very useful to know which command do that. For example, Assign Bloq Mayusc to the Mod Key